# sequelize migrations after models were created

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

I'm searching for method to create migrations and create database from models that was already on app since pull from github. I'm using AWS so I need to run migrations build command on app build and connect it with AWS RDS. What I did so far - created `.sequelizerc` with the following contents

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('lib', './app.database.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('lib', './models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('lib', './seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('lib', './migrations')
}
```

and have all models stored in `/lib/models/` folder with the following structure for example

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Init = sequelize.define('Init', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    version: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
    tableName: 'oc_init',
    timestamps: false
});

return Init;
};
```

need to mention that some of the models already has prototypes itself with additional libraries in use, such a bcrypt etc.

So after app build I'm trying to run `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` and the following error appears

> No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.

but as I check the remote database (amazon RDS) I can only see `SequelizeMeta` table created. What I'm doing wrong? How to create migrations on my local machine so I could migrate data on AWS?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to create migrations for each model by myself describing its contents and run `sequelize db:migrate`. It appears there are no methods to create migration files from already created models.